# Characters before doctype and after html tag viewed by rexswain http sniffer

Tags: html, doctype, sniffer

Most of websites when shown with the http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html viewer display some extra characters before the `DOCTYPE` and also after the ending `HTML` tag.
Is this really sent by the server or it's a bug of the rexswain viewer ?

EDIT:
For example, the first 2 lines of [drupalfrance.com](http://drupalfrance.com) are

```
7add(CR)(LF)
<!DOCTYPE·html·PUBLIC·"-//W3C//DTD·XHTML+RDFa·1.0//EN"(LF)
```

and the 4 last lines are

```
</html>(LF)
(CR)(LF)
0(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)
```

Comment: It's not BOM neither LF, it's for example </htm(CR)(LF)
3(CR)(LF)
l>(LF)
(CR)(LF)
0(CR)(LF)

Comment: At AMAZON I get two hex chars before the LFs so that is what I thought you meant.

Comment: Yes, the 18af (and 2 Tabs), but it's not BOM, and there should be no LF before DOCTYPE. With other sniffer, I do not see these characters.

Comment: You should specify, by URL, actual examples and describe the location and identity of the extra characters.

Comment: When using fiddler to inspect the traffic for drupalfrance.com I don't see those characters. There is some line breaks after the end of file but no non-whitespace characters (and not as many linebreaks as you are showing). It is possible that fiddler is doing some trimming but it seems unlikely, especially in the area between the headers and the body of the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the HTTP header, notice `Transfer Encoding: chunked`.

The hexadecimal number (followed by CR,LF) is the number of characters in the following chunk.  In your case, `7add = 31453`.  Then 0,CR,LF indicates the end.

Comment: So Rex Swain’s utility (like the `telnet` program on Unix, for example) is showing the actual bytes received, without interpreting chunking. I guess this is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense. In my fiddler tests it automatically assembled the chunked content so hid that info from me (until your answer made me go look again). :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, the RexSwain shows the chunked size ! Telnet shows this also when asked by HTTP/1.1